# HQL excluyente entre tablas

Tags: hibernate, hql

Necesito un par de Querys excluyentes para comprobar un factor "disponibilidad" dentro de una db.

Vale la query hasta el momento la he ido planteando de diversas maneras y creo, que esta es la más correcta pero me sigue dando error

```
    from Usuario judge where judge.juez = 1 and judge.idusuario  not in Usuariomaraton
```

Alguien me podría decir qué es lo que falla de la query por lo que no consigo extraer lo que busco (Todos los usuarios que tengan valor juez 1 y no estén en la tabla Usuariomaraton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo mira en sql seria así

```
select * from Usuario judge where judge.juez = 1 and judge.idusuario  not in 
(select idusuario from Usuariomaraton)
```

si te fijas el 'in' lo asocio a una consulta y no a un objeto revisa en la documentacion subconsultas 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/es-ES/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!!! por favor podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien solo como referencia [answer]. Bienvenido!